# Should I have a seperate table for each media type

Tags: django, database-design, django-models

See initially I thought this would be simple but this is killing me right now

I have a post model which contains a field (foreign key to media)

Media has 3 colums Image, Video, Audio (each related to their own tables)

And each of those three tables above has 1 file field (except for image because that holds x and y coordinated too for the tagging purpose) I don't wanna disturb the order of the upload(the size if the field is gonna change in future because I have to store a thumbnail for each file)

let's say a user uploaded a picture first and then audio and then a video I wanna display them in the order as they were uploaded but I really don't know how to achieve this

Can anyone please help me figure out, what should I do to implement this

Comment: What if you make **m2m** relation from Post to Image, Audio, Video through Media? Media would have a generic relation to either Image, Audio, Video. You could use `DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)` to capture the upload time and use it for ordering.

Comment: But i want something like position, i've seen that on many model designs

Comment: What is that something like position? I'm afraid I don't understand you. With my suggestion you'd have different models for Image, Video, Audio. Everytime an entry is persisted, upload time will be saved. Those models will have a generic relation to model Medium, and Medium will be related to Post. You will fetch all media for a post and order them by uploading time.

Comment: Maybe you should expand your question and provide the relevant parts of the code you have (`models.py`).

Comment: By position i mean this https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/django-positionfield/

Comment: Whenever you create a new  Media, Just add date-time field in 3 tables (image, audio, video) and from that you can get which is older and new respectively

Comment: But i can't let my users repositon their media with this datetimefield approach